# How correctly type function that updates values of specified fields of object

Tags: typescript

I've implemented a function that accepts object, callback and array containing keys of this object. This function updates value of every field specified in the array using callback provided in arguments.

Example:

```
const foo = { a: 3, b: 4, c: 4 }
const bar = updateFields(foo, (val) => val + 10, ['a', 'b'])

console.log(bar) // { a: 13, b: 14, c: 4 }
```

Right now I have this function implemented and tested, so it works ok.

```
const updateFields = <T extends {}, K extends keyof T, V>(
  obj: T,
  callback: (val: T[K]) => V,
  fields: K[]
) =>
  Object.entries<T[K]>(obj).reduce(
    (acc, [key, value]) => {
      if (fields.includes(key as K)) {
        acc[key] = callback(value)
      } else {
        acc[key] = value
      }

      return acc
    },
    {} as any
  )
```

What I'm interested in is how to correctly write types for this function, especially the return type, as right now I have it implicitly set to `any`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`updateFields` will have return type `{ [P in K]: V } & Omit<T, K>` - all properties `K` in `fields` are updated to value `V` while the rest of the properties is preserved.

In `reduce` operations there is always some form of assertion/cast necessary, if a new object is iteratively constructed one property after the other. In your concrete example you can ease up the function body by iterating over the `fields` array, not the original object properties of `T`. That will save you the `key as K` cast and conditional logic.

```
const updateFields = <T extends object, K extends keyof T, V>(
  obj: T,
  callback: (val: T[K]) => V,
  fields: K[]
): Omit<T, K> & { [P in K]: V } => ({
  ...obj,
  ...fields.reduce(
    (acc, cur) => {
      // ... or use spread here
      acc[cur] = callback(obj[cur]);
      return acc;
    },
    {} as { [P in K]: V } // this cast is (almost always) necessary
  )
});
```

Let's make the example more obvious by choosing a string type for `c`:

```
const foo = { a: 3, b: 4, c: "foo" };

// const bar: Pick<{a: number; b: number; c: string}, "c"> & {a: number; b: number;}
const bar = updateFields(foo, val => val + 10, ["a", "b"]);

console.log(bar); // { a: 13, b: 14, c: "foo" }
```

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBArgBwCYEMoFMBiBLdAbJCGAXhgB4AVGdADwzEJhACMArdYKAGhgGlq66BkQDW6AJ4gAZjAo8AagD4AFACgYTNgC5ZXdTGAo8eZimAidygG5GdFANq8AugEoSimPL0apuAhB1eeydVFx0AeQBbbChKHl4PADIYAG8YewAFGGwwPicdeRgAX3cYZRT9ADpqllZvGGrK33xCSoAndCQ4YHQ1DQ1lM2AeYDg2t2IPCv7+gHpZhuqmNpgjCBB4CHQYCAQOlCQYAAt0Dv0ZoftRtqcSAyMTMxFlWqux1wBuc-6OqDHcoZfGZFeoaFIlFBENKZbK5ZwFYr6FyqIouL6qUCQWBSEAbUhpFA6ADMPGYOgALCMdAAiHEganFdHzAzgaAwUxtHQZbDmMgpQkwMBwSLMU4fdk6IUisUGHTQNo5ADmIJg1OA1KSqQFUtFbXFZMFwt1HyKGNZsA5d0QqAwOBaEGUdJ4NjwpRdMAA1DAAIwABh49mpKGpPGpzGpn1UZsgIDw6EqeBAiuUHLRMGZBJ03pJEp9lNlqrpDKKQA)